# In for loop in python, Why the start point doesn't print when the increment is negative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In python,
`for x in range(1,3,1):`
`print(x)`
and the answer is:
`1`
`2`.

But when we type,
`for x in range(1,3,-1):`
`print(x)`
and the answer is:
`<Nothing>`
why 1 isn't printed in the second code?
Although the increment is false. However the starting integer must be printed?? isn't it??

Comment: Why doesn't the end point print when the increment is positive? Same thing; just in a different direction.

Comment: Also, see [What is the rational for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918) -- questions about *how to solve a specific problem* are on-topic here. Once you know how to fix your code (which you clearly do), you no longer _have_ a specific problem, but are asking a question out of curiosity; those questions often lead to debates or folks pushing their own opinions (not necessarily based on facts or evidence), and otherwise generate "more heat than light".

Answer (score 2):

The starting point is printed only if it is in the range you defined with `range`. Here, `range(1, 3, -1)` corresponds to the empty set, since you cannot reach 3 from 1 by adding -1 each time.

You can read more about it on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), where r[0] corresponds to the starting point:

> A range object will be empty if r[0] does not meet the value constraint. Ranges do support negative indices, but these are interpreted as indexing from the end of the sequence determined by the positive indices.